# Mocha assertions not returning correctly on assert.equal with BN

Tags: solidity, testing, mocha

Is this an issue with deep matching/object identity?

```
AssertionError: expected <BN: 204fce5e3e25026110000000> to equal <BN: 204fce5e3e25026110000000>
```

It seems strange that chai.should seems to work fine with the same vars:

```
// works
supplyCap.should.be.bignumber.equal(_cap);

// doesn't work
assert.equal(supplyCap, _cap);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
assert.equal(supplyCap, _cap);
```

To this:

```
assert.equal(supplyCap.toString(), _cap.toString());
```

Comment: Makes sense. This is because there is some internal difference between the objects?

Comment: @errata: I think that `assert.equal` just uses `==`, and since you're passing two different objects, it fails. You can verify my conjecture by calling `assert.equal(supplyCap, supplyCap)` and see if it passes.

Comment: interesting point.. thx again

Answer (score 1):

Consider using **[bn-chai](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/bn-chai/)** if you do it a lot.

Then you can do:

```
expect(new BN('1')).to.eq.BN(new BN('1'));
expect(new BN('1')).to.eq.BN('1');
expect(new BN('1')).to.eq.BN(1);
```

Comment: Ya that does look a lot more pleasant. Perhaps I'll try to migrate. thx!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this solution applies to your case, but whenever I handle numbers from smart contracts I use the Number(...) constructor as follows.

```
assert.equal(Number(supplyCap), Number(_cap));
```

And works perfectly for me.